# Is grub.conf read by GRUBX64.EFI from SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI?

Tags: uefi

Does the following mean that `SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI` executes first, then `GRUBX64.EFI`, which then reads `grub.conf`?

```
#> efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0001,000B,0005,000D,000C,0002
Boot0001* Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,e0.... \SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0002* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  VenMedia(5023...012)..BO
Boot0003* arch HD(1,GPT,e07236...921eed1e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ARCH\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0005* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)......BO
Boot000B* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,e07236...000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot000C* Unknown Device    BBS(11,,0x0)..GO..NO........y.G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .S.T.O.R.A.G.E. .D.E.V.I.C.E. 
Boot000D* UEFI: Generic STORAGE DEVICE 0272 PciRoot(0x...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means that your default boot loader is `SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI` ( whatever that is ).  `ARCH\GRUBX64.EFI` is only used if you choose it from the boot menu, or the first choice returns an error.

Comment: Doesn't that contradict the `BootOrder`?  I was reading `BootOrder` as:  0003/"GRUBX64.efi" as the default and 0001/"SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.efi" as the fallback?

Comment: @dgo.a, oops, you are right... I was looking at BootCurrent, which says you booted the systemd one this time, but indeed, it is not the default.